# google-chrome starts a new session when I click a link

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome

When I click a link in a terminal window (like when I'm using trn or mutt) or in the Quassel IRC client, instead of creating a new window or tab in the existing Google Chrome session, it creates a new instance of Chrome.  And even if I shut that one down first, it sort of "takes over" so if I shutdown Chrome or log out and log back in, the "Continue where I left off" On Startup option means I only see the one link, instead of all the tabs I had open before.

Is there something I can configure to make those applications use the existing Chrome instance instead of starting a new one?

(This is Kubuntu 12.10)

**Update**: it appears this behaviour, of starting a new session instead of using the existing one, only happens when it restarts Chrome after I log off and back in.  If I start Chrome from the menu button, all works correctly and links clicked in Konsole or Quassel open up in new tabs on existing windows.

Comment: I can confirm the issue on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 too.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the last google chrome beta version there it works perfectly.

https://www.google.com/intl/eng/chrome/browser/beta.html

if you do in terminal:
    `google-chrome (web-adress`)
What is the output than?

Comment: If I just type "google-chrome http://slashdot.org/" it opens up a new tab in an existing Chrome window.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here.

Looks as if it konsole runs chrome with the `--new-window` switch.

not a kde guy, but try editing

```
~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals

[General]
BrowserApplication[$e]=!google-chrome
```

right now it's probably set to `google-chrome --new-window`

there should be a similar config file specific for konsole. `konsolerc`. But I think that konsole doesn't have its own browser option.